# Suspend all process of specific user

Tags: linux

In Linux system.

Like skill -KILL -u vivek, will kill all process of user vivek, is there a command to suspend all user prosess of a specific user , and for resume it all, later ?

Comment: i'm pretty sure if you kill any processes for any user, you can't magically put in a command and start them all back up.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of *SIGKILL*, you can use the *SIGTSTP* signal, which causes processes receiving it to stop. However, a process can register a signal handler for or ignore *SIGTSTP*. A process can also be paused with the *SIGSTOP* signal, which cannot be caught or ignored.

Use *SIGCONT* to resume the processes.